What are some examples of elegant solutions?
There are various problems in history such as the Basel problem which was solved by Euler using the Taylor expansion of the sine, then later by Cauchy by bounding the partial sum, both solutions were very elegant. Another example would be the Gaussian integral which was solved by Poisson using polar coordinates. I find such solutions to be very clever and elegant. So ,what are some other examples of solutions or results which were solved in elegant and creative way?

Judging by examples, what you mean by "elegant" is using a short, unexpected and (seemingly) unrelated construction. Dandelin spheres give an 'elegant' proof of the focal property of the ellipse, for example, permutational proof of Fermat-Euler is 'elegant'. Math SE and MO have threads with more examples.

Is this question only related to calculus? (per tag)

@Conifold: if you have seen the proof of inscribed square problem which seems to be a geometric problem but was solved using ideas of topology, its like you pull the unique creative ideas from another dimension and connect them cleverly ,which from a glance seems so obscure ,that is what i call elegant!

@Mauricio: for all field of maths ,physics ,chess or any other form which is science as well as art!

There is a famous book by the mathematicians Günter Ziegler and Martin Aigner devoted to the search of the most beautiful proofs in mathematics, the first edition of which was published in 1998:
Proofs from the Book, Springer.
There is now a sixth edition, of 2018.
The authors spent 20 years collecting the most beautiful proofs in mathematics.
The book is dedicated to the famous mathematicians Paul Erdös, who spoke of a Book where God wrote the most beautiful proofs of mathematics.
Erdös himself suggested some proofs that must be present in the Book.
The book has been translated in at least thirteen languages.
Here an interview to Ziegler and  Aigner, in which they talk about their aesthetical criteria:
https://www.wired.com/story/in-search-of-gods-mathematical-perfect-proofs/
Below also a thread on MathStackExchange about the Proofs that every mathematician should know:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/178940/proofs-that-every-mathematician-should-know
